# Parse platform: 209 Invalid session token in Auth.js

Tags: parse-platform

I have a mobile app that uses Parse's anonymous user to save some data.

The iOS swift code looks like this:

```
    PFAnonymousUtils.logIn{ (user, error) in
        if let user = user, error == nil {
            //save data linked to this user
            locationObject.acl = PFACL.init(user: user)
            locationObject["user"] = user
            locationObject.saveInBackground { (succeeded, error)  in
                ...
            }
        }else if let error = error {
            //handle error
        }
    }
```

At the server side, the server config is initialised such that there is no expiration on the sessions:

```
var api = new ParseServer({
    ...
  expireInactiveSessions: false
});
```

The idea is that we do not want the session for the anonymous users to expire at all if possible.

The above codes will work fine.

But 4 weeks ago, this server crashed. Massive amount of "208 Auth is already used" error can be seen in the console logs. It appears that suddenly all users were facing that error, and the server ran out of memory.

Restarting the server didn't help. The only solution we did is to DELETE all the users and sessions on MongoDB, and then suddenly the server recovers.

4 weeks later, the server crashed again. This time, it is massive amount of "209 invalid session token". At this point of time there is about 70k users and 70k sessions in the database. Again, it appear that suddenly everyone is facing this issue and driving the server out of memory:

```
error: Invalid session token message=Invalid session token, stack=Error: Invalid session token
at Object.getAuthForSessionToken (/app/node_modules/parse-server/lib/Auth.js:114:11)
at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5), code=209
```

My first suspicion is that all users token expired AT THE SAME TIME but that didn't make sense because we have configured expireInactiveSessions to false. Also, when investigating Auth.js on parse server, if session expired the error should be "Session token is expired." but we never see that error in the console logs.

What could be the problem, causing massive amount of invalid session token or auth is already used errors to happen at the same time for all users?

I am using Parse server 3.2.3.

Comment: What do you have in place for the `sessionLength` option?

Comment: We are having the same issue right now. Did you figure out what was the problem?

Comment: @FeiXie unfortunately we didn't have a conclusion. For my case it appears that the issue happens periodically whenever the number of sessions reaches 70k+. So we wonder is it because our server is not efficient enough, we tried to add redis cache adaptor, and do indexing on mongodb, then right now it can sustain for more than 4 weeks now and sessions going to 150k+. Still not sure will the old problem haunt us again. Do let me know if you have findings cheers!